# Error on rendering yii view

Tags: php, yii, yii-routing

The following URL part works as expected on my Windows WAMP machine (running using AMPPS), but fails on the Linux production host:

index.php?r=customchocolates/index

I get the following error:
Unable to resolve the request "customchocolates/index"

On Windows, I followed the naming convention of CustomChocolates in all the relevant files. However, after searching on-line, I changed the following files to:
controller: customChocolatesController.php
model: customChocolates.php
views dir: customChocolates

I've also updated all the class names to the new name, but I'm still getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

Windows = file name case insensitive

Linux = file name case sensitive

Change your route to `customChocolates/index`

Comment: Thanks, @nkamm for a reply. Does that mean I have to also change all the other files, too? Cuz I tried your suggestion and it still gave me the same error...

Comment: Can you share the route in configuration?

Comment: im new to yii. can you explain what you mean by route in configuration? do routes need to be defined explicityly?

Comment: Routes are rules for CUrlManager. I prefer to define rules explicitly, but there is default pattern "Controller/Method". You changed your URL (not a route as I believe, i.e. you use this generic route). So try rename your file (as Mikhail said).

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#user-friendly-urls Try rename your file and classname first. The problem of not rendered view is not in view, but in fact that Yii can't find your controller

Answer (score 1):

Try to rename `customChocolatesController.php` to `CustomChocolatesController.php`, and be sure, that controller class name also `CustomChocolatesController`.
And rename you route as **nkamm** says.

Comment: tried that when I first uploaded the site because that's how I had it on my Windows machine.. and it didnt work. Tried it again now.. again, didnt work...

Comment: Try to re-create file with controller on Windows machine with right file name, it may help.

Comment: I can't recreate the problem on my Windows machine.. whatever permutation of customchocolates I give it.. it renders the index view. =/

Comment: Have you upload newly created file from Windows to Linux machine? Be sure, that file with new file name appears in Linux machine

Comment: i got the site working on my Linux laptop. I can reproduce the error now. But I can't solve it. :(

Answer (score 0):

Moved my site to my Linux laptop to reproduce the problem. Got the same problem as on production.

I solved it (I don't know why - perhaps someone more knowledgeable and experienced can explain) by doing the following:

1. renamed controller file and class names to CustomchocolatesController
2. Removed caseSensitive from URLManager block in config
3. Renamed views folder to customchocolates

Thanks to @nkamm and @Mihail for their time last night.